# Filter Search Results For PNG images only

Tags: javascript, image, api, google-custom-search

I copied most of the code from the Google docs, and then used the documentation to set the filter.

- I don't get any errors
- But the FILETYPE_PNG is not working (`the filetype never gets restricted)`

I used
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#filetype

Does anybody know what's wrong with the code?

I also tried doing a `searcher.execute("Kobe Bryant");` - but it still did not restrict to PNG only.

```
google.load('search', '1', {language: 'en', style: google.loader.themes.MINIMALIST});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  var customSearchOptions = {};
  var orderByOptions = {};
  orderByOptions['keys'] = [{label: 'Relevance', key: ''} , {label: 'Date', key: 'date'}];
  customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
  customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;
  var imageSearchOptions = {};
  //imageSearchOptions['layout'] = LAYOUT_POPUP;  -- layout popup causing errors for some reason
  customSearchOptions['enableImageSearch'] = true;
  customSearchOptions['disableWebSearch'] = true;
  var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('Youaintfindingoutwhatthisis', customSearchOptions);
  customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.SMALL_RESULTSET);

  var searcher = customSearchControl.getImageSearcher();
  searcher.setRestriction(
    customSearchControl.getImageSearcher.RESTRICT_FILETYPE,
    customSearchControl.getImageSearcher.FILETYPE_PNG
  );

  var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
  options.setAutoComplete(true);
  customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
}, true);
```

---

UPDATE

- see my answer below
- still don't know what's up with LAYOUT_POPUP - I get an undefined error here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

The documentation is a little misleading.

You need the following code to get filtering to work:

```
customSearchControl.setSearchStartingCallback(
  this, function(control, searcher, query) {
      searcher.setQueryAddition("filetype:png OR filetype:PNG");
  }
);
```

Place this at the end of the js file. Hope this helps anyone else struggling with the documentation.

Comment: @Jeremy Do you know what's wrong with LAYOUT_POPUP? I get an undefined error for it for some reason

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with this.

Comment: How does the URL look like with such an "OR"?